# Collect all not in using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this small snipped of code.

I don't know ruby and I think this is a great opportunity to apply it.

I want to print all the lines in file `e` which are not in file  `c`. Each line is a number.

This is what I've got:

```
 e = File.new('e').readlines
 c = File.new('c').readlines

 x = e.collect do |item|
   c.include?( item ) ? "" : item
 end

 p x.sort
```

The problem is that both file may have empty spaces and for that reason the same number may not be considered as such. ( eg. "1234  " is different from "  1234 " )

What do I need in my code to fix it? I've tried `c.include?(item.strip)` .. .but doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps doing the `strip` when you do the `readlines` would help, i.e.

```
e = File.readlines('e').map{|x| x.strip}
c = File.readlines('c').map{|x| x.strip}
```

Then you could use `collect` as you did, or perhaps `select` if you don't want the empty strings:

```
x = e.select{|i| !c.include?(i)}
```

**Edit**: or as [Benno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92560/benno) suggests, use

```
x = e-c
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- you can use the minus operator for sets
- why not convert to integers if each line is an integer?

```
  File.readlines("e").map(&:to_i) - File.readlines("c").map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the items to actual numbers. Also, you should be closing those files after reading from them. File.new opens but does not close. You can open it in a block to automatically close it. Try:

```
e = nil
c = nil
File.open('e'){|file|
    e = file.readlines
    e.map!{|x| x.to_i}
}
File.open('c'){|file|
    c = file.readlines
    c.map!{|x| x.to_i}
}
```

To create the arrays of numbers.